# Search all within opened tabs with Sublime Text 2

Tags: search, text-editors, sublime-text-2, sublime-text

Having Sublime Text 2 Text Editor:

Is it possible to search within all the tabs that are open? How?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on a Mac.

or just go to the menu "Find" and use the option almost at the bottom called "Find in Files".

To search in all open files, add this to the Where textbox:

```
<open files>
```

If you want to search in folders and such, please just look at the right of the textbox and see there's a button `...`. Click on it and it will show you options.

Comment: Mamsaac's answer is also supported in Sublime Text 3, for those who are wondering.

Comment: When I try this (Sublime Text 3.1.1 on Mac OS), it doesn't search all open tabs; it only searches open tabs within the current window.

Comment: You can also leave the "WHERE" text box Empty instead of typing `<open files>`.